# AngularJS sort People into Alphabetical List and Filter

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, alphabetical

In AngularJS I have an Object with keys that are letters of the alphabet and each key is an array of people.

```
<div ng-repeat="(letter, group) in people"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="people in letter"></div>
</div>
```

This is to create something like this in HTML:

```
A. Arnold, Avery, Adam, Alex
B. Bob, Boris
C. Chris, Connor, Caleb
```

How would I go about filtering each individual field by name? For example applying this.

```
<div ng-repeat="people in letter | filter:{'name':search.query}">
```

Works fine, however, you get a result like this when you type "A" in:

```
A. Arnold, Avery, Adam, Alex
B. 
C.
```

How can I collapse B and C? Is there a better organization method for this data?

Comment: should be able to add an `ng-if` and use array length as value

Comment: @charlieftl you're right, but the parent container for the letter still remains and can not access the child array length. I was hoping to also collapse the parent so it doesn't appeat empty.

Comment: please show data structure. Also show how you tried using `ng-if` . I don't see why it won't work

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to store your filtered names in a scope variable so you can do a length check to hide the empty result.

You can do this with the following markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="people in filtered = (group | filter: search)"></div>
```

Then add `ng-if="filtered.length > 0"` to the tag you want to hide if result is 0.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/xz3mk3gu/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.peoples = {
        A: ['Arnold', 'Avery', 'Adam', 'Alex'],
        B: ['Bob', 'Boris'],
        C: ['Chris', 'Connor', 'Caleb']
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <input ng-model="search" placeholder="enter search string"></input>
<div ng-repeat="(letter, group) in peoples">
    <strong ng-if="filtered.length > 0">{{letter}}</strong>
    <div ng-repeat="people in filtered = (group | filter: search)">{{people}}</div>
    <br ng-if="filtered.length > 0"/>
</div>
</div>
```